# is soldering mobile processors something that i could do at home?

Tags: soldering

I want to connect a mobile processor such as a Samsung Exynos or Qualcomm Snapdragon, which both have their connectors on the bottom to a PCB but im not sure if this is something i can do on my own or needs a pick and place machine, to be honest im not entirely sure what the method of soldering used is called. Can you please inform me if a socket is available for these also? Sorry if this came across as a dumb question, thanks for the help :)

Comment: connect to where?

Comment: Any image will help to analyze. Can u provide?

Comment: You are talking about BGA (ball grid array) ICs here. It's pretty difficult and you will need specialized machinery as well as materials to pull it off. Besides these, you need some experience (which I think you are lacking). There are BGA to DIP adapters available on the internet but they appear to be expensive. If I were you, I'd have got it done by a professional.

Comment: Do you also intend to design and build the PCB yourself or do you already have one?

Comment: @RogerRowland i am going to make one myself. It would just be to connect it to a breadboard to start with.

Comment: Then that's not trivial either, you'd need more than one layer and would need vias and decoupling caps, a real tough job even for a pro. You'd better set your sights a little lower!

Comment: *Can you please inform me if a socket is available for these also?* There probably are but since you have to ask I'm quite sure you cannot afford one. Such sockets are used for testing only not for using in a product.

Comment: Erm, you are trying to connect a several hundred pin processor which runs are several hundred MHz to a breadboard?? You really need to reanalyse your plans.

Comment: I think you can safely **forget** about making mobile phone/ raspberry pi type complexity on a home-build system. This requires knowledge and experience only to be found in professional environments. Start with a simpler microcontroller based board without BGA packaged ICs. You'll have enough trouble with that in the beginning.

Comment: That's cute. Connecting a 1000 pin IC to a breadboard. I hope you have a large breadboard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to solder components with contacts on the bottom (called Ball Grid Array, or BGA) using a soldering iron.  You would need either a reflow oven, or a BGA rework station.

Some people do have reflow ovens at home, or have converted toaster ovens to do the job, but even then it's a bit tricky and easy to mess up.

So the answer to your question is yes, you can do this at home if you have the right tools, but if you only have a soldering iron then you can't.

Comment: To add to this, soldering companies use some sort of X Ray machine to verify the soldering quality which costs thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it dead bug style:
[image]

Is it practical or is it going to work, especially in an 1000+ balls device?

I don't think so...

(Image from the comments area from [Hackaday website](http://hackaday.com/2016/01/03/bga-hand-soldering-video/))

Comment: The... the horror!

Comment: That hurts to look at

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, the bottom of a mobile processor has a lot of pins that are too small for you to handle and would need a reflow oven.

[image: Bottom of a CPU]

Comment: A reflow oven is pretty cheap. Lots of hobbyists have one in one form or another.

Comment: Yes. It is called "heat gun", $30 or something. And lots of hobbysts can afford to make 10-12-16 layer boards with buried vias, to get proper wire fan-out for 1000+ pins, with 0201 bypass caps. Yes!

Comment: @AliChen: Getting the chip on there might be possible but if it doesn't work then you have practically no way to find out why, besides desoldering it again, but then how are you going to re-ball it at home?  Totally impractical.

Comment: Absolutely.  Yield will reek to the point that any prototype will have zero testing value, so you may as well skip the step.